# Защита от спама в телеграм боте

Tags: python, aiogram

Я пишу тг бота на aiogram, но есть проблема. Пользователь может просто отправить сразу 10 команд и они все по очереди будут выполнятся. Как наиболее правильно сделать так, чтобы пока выбранный хэндлер не отработал, в ответ на все сообщения пользователя ему писалось "Подождите"?